# Angular-UI Bootstrap toggle buttons in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap

I originally had the default Bootstrap 3.3 toggle buttons in my app.  These are the grouping of buttons that mimic the behavior of checkboxes or radio buttons.

I was trying to replace them with the ones [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/buttons)

I paste the code into my html, and at first it looks fine:

[image]

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <label class="btn btn-default" ng-model="checkModel.left" btn-checkbox>Left</label>
  <label class="btn btn-default" ng-model="checkModel.middle" btn-checkbox>Middle</label>
  <label class="btn btn-default" ng-model="checkModel.right" btn-checkbox>Right</label>
</div>
```

Now I want to hook up the controller.  So, I create a file "elements-buttons.controller.js" with the contents of the JS from the angular-ui site:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('pb.ds.elements').controller('ButtonsController',
    function($log) {
      var _this = this;
      _this.singleModel = 1;
      _this.radioModel = 'Middle';
      _this.checkModel = {
        left: false,
        middle: true,
        right: false
      };
    });
})();
```

I put the controller into my router:

```js
.state('elements.buttons', {
  url: '/elements/buttons',
  templateUrl: 'modules/elements/templates/elements-buttons.html',
  controller: 'ButtonsController as buttons'
})
```

Now, **as soon as I link the controller to my index.html**, the button group loses all styling:

[image]

Which makes no sense to me at all.  Inspecting the code in Chrome shows it's if fact lost all its classes for some reason:

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <label class="" ng-model="buttons.checkModel.left" btn-checkbox="">Left</label>
  <label class="" ng-model="buttons.checkModel.middle" btn-checkbox="">Middle</label>
  <label class="" ng-model="buttons.checkModel.right" btn-checkbox="">Right</label>
</div>
```

Now, since I have used "controller as" syntax, I did make sure to try adding that to the model `ng-model="buttons.checkModel.right"` but with or without this same thing.  No controller, looks fine.  Controller, boom.

EDIT/UPDATE:  There are no errors in the console of any kind.

Comment: Try controllerAs: in the .state definitions

Comment: But I have many state, all with controller as syntax and this works perfectly with all of them: `controller: 'ChartColorsController as charts',`

Comment: @Steve Can you post fiddle of your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a jsfiddle in order to debug your problem.

[Check it here.](http://jsfiddle.net/vd2Lwng9/32/)

And Im finding no problems on it.

Key points you should check:

- Be sure you are adding all neccessaries files, such as ui-bootstrap.js
- ui-bootstrap.css
- jquery, since this are just directives for angular, it will also need jQuery (as the original bootstrap does)
- include the dependency on ui-bootstrap on you app definition, pay attention to this line -> `angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap', 'app.controllers']);`
- ng-app & ng-controller on the markup. Be sure you are not forgetting this

On the fiddle, Im not using ui-router, but you should check that the controller is indeed loading (you can add a console.log there and check that the controller is loaded).

I thing with this guidelines and the jsfiddle, you should be good to go

Comment: I'll try it, but the odd thing is that every other page in my app that uses bootstrap directives work perfectly.  this is the only one causing an issue.

Comment: Did you have any update ? Did you try my suggestions ? You can also prepare a jsfiddle to reproduce your issue, in case mine was not enough.